# TypeError: contacts.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
app.get("/contacts/:phone",(req,res)=>{
   var name = req.params.name;
   var filteredNames = contacts.filter((c)=>{
       return c.name == name;
   });

   filteredNames.find({},{projection:{_id:0}}).toArray((err,contactsArray)=>{

       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           res.send(contactsArray);
       }
   });


});
```

Al ejecutar este código me dice que contacts.filter no es una función , ¿por qué me está dando error?
Contacts es mi colección de mongodb

Comment: Hola @RoyalUp, ¿tienes declarada la variable 'contacts' en el código? Es que en la porción de código no aparece declarada.

Comment: Claro está declarada

Comment: Podrías poner mas código para poder ayudarte a resolver tu problema porque con esta info no sabría ayudarte.

Comment: Veo que intentas usar el método `filter` del objeto `contacts`. ¿Ese método existe en tu objeto? En otras preguntas que has realizado, parece que `contacts` es una instancia de un modelo de Mongoose. ¿Tienes claro lo que estás intentando? Saludos